# JFrame not being written to

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jframe

My JFrame is opening to a blank window.
I tried to create an instance of the calcView class in order to open and write to the JFrame Window but it didn't work properly.
Basically I have to use the MVC method to develop a multiplication only calculator so I have 3 separate classes shown here:
CalcView

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.awt.*;
public class CalcView extends JFrame{
      private static final String INITIAL_VALUE = "1";

    private JTextField m_totalTf = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField m_userInputTf = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton m_multiplyBtn = new JButton("Multiply");
    private JButton m_clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");

    private BigInteger m_total; // The total current value state.

   public void CalcGUI() {
         JFrame window = new CalcView();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         window.setTitle("Performs Simple Multiplications");
         window.setVisible(true);
        m_total = new BigInteger(INITIAL_VALUE);
        m_totalTf.setText(INITIAL_VALUE);
        m_totalTf.setEditable(false);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(new JLabel("Input"));
        content.add(m_userInputTf);
        content.add(m_multiplyBtn);
        content.add(new JLabel("Total"));
        content.add(m_totalTf);
        content.add(m_clearBtn);

        this.setContentPane(content);
        this.pack();
   
    }
    public void throwExcept(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CalcView.this, "Bad Number");
    }
}
```

CalcModel

```
import java.awt.event.*;
public class CalcModel{
    public static final String INITIAL_VALUE = "1";
    
    public float multiply(){
        float i = 0;
        return i;
    }
}
```

CalcController

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class CalcController {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CalcView v = new CalcView();
    v.CalcGUI();
    }
  
    public void listener() {
        m_clearBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_total = new BigInteger(INITIAL_VALUE);
                m_totalTf.setText(INITIAL_VALUE);
            }
        });
        m_multiplyBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    CalcModel m = new CalcModel();
                    m.multiply(e);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nex) {
                   CalcView v = new CalcView();
                   v.throwExcept();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Additionally, How can I pass event handlers between classes?

Comment: *Additionally, How can I pass event handlers between classes?* - one question per posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you add a content panel to the wrong JFrame.
In this line of code you made a new JFrame.

```
JFrame window = new CalcView();
```

But in these line of codes you add the content JPanel to the CalcView class it self.

```
this.setContentPane(content);
this.pack();
```

There is two option to make it visible, the first one is don't extend JFrame, and add the content JPanel to the window JFrame. The second option is extend JFrame and don't create a new window JFrame.

The first option is shown in code below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.awt.*;
public class CalcView{
    private static final String INITIAL_VALUE = "1";

    private JTextField m_totalTf = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField m_userInputTf = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton m_multiplyBtn = new JButton("Multiply");
    private JButton m_clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");

    private BigInteger m_total; // The total current value state.

    JFrame window = new JFrame();

    public void CalcGUI() {
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle("Performs Simple Multiplications");
        window.setVisible(true);
        m_total = new BigInteger(INITIAL_VALUE);
        m_totalTf.setText(INITIAL_VALUE);
        m_totalTf.setEditable(false);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(new JLabel("Input"));
        content.add(m_userInputTf);
        content.add(m_multiplyBtn);
        content.add(new JLabel("Total"));
        content.add(m_totalTf);
        content.add(m_clearBtn);

        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.pack();
    }

    public void throwExcept(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Bad Number");
    }
}
```

The second option is shown in code below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.awt.*;
public class CalcView extends JFrame{
    private static final String INITIAL_VALUE = "1";

    private JTextField m_totalTf = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField m_userInputTf = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton m_multiplyBtn = new JButton("Multiply");
    private JButton m_clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");

    private BigInteger m_total; // The total current value state.

    public void CalcGUI() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Performs Simple Multiplications");
        this.setVisible(true);
        m_total = new BigInteger(INITIAL_VALUE);
        m_totalTf.setText(INITIAL_VALUE);
        m_totalTf.setEditable(false);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(new JLabel("Input"));
        content.add(m_userInputTf);
        content.add(m_multiplyBtn);
        content.add(new JLabel("Total"));
        content.add(m_totalTf);
        content.add(m_clearBtn);

        this.setContentPane(content);
        this.pack();

    }
    public void throwExcept(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CalcView.this, "Bad Number");
    }
}
```

Additionally, You can pass event handlers between classes by using constructor or simply create a setter function. You can read more about constructor here https://www.javatpoint.com/java-constructor.